# Merging an already (locally) deleted folder

Tags: merge, mercurial, abort

I'm using Mercurial and ran into an issue I'm not sure how to resolve. The issue I'm facing at the moment is as follows:

- We had a project (folder) that was initially called A and pushed that to a remote repository.
- I renamed Project A to B and pushed it to the remote repository. While doing so, I also locally renamed Project A to B.
- Project A was removed from the remote repository.
- I tried to pull those changes but Mercurial seems to get confused as the files (or paths to files) do not exist locally anymore.

If I'm invoking '`hg merge`', the following output is produced:
"Abort: outstanding uncommitted changes, ..."
If I then invoke '`hg status`', all the files which were in the initial version of Project A are listed - which now are not locally available anymore because the paths have changed from `A/.../...` to `B/.../...`

Can anybody give me a hint or tip on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the listed files listed as "deleted" (R I think)?

If yes, just commit this change (about the deleted files), then merge. Mercurial have to know about all the changes, including the files moved or removed.

Comment: Grr, hitting 'return' too early. Well, if I understood correctly, the files marked with 'R' are in the store ATM cause I've received them with a changeset when I pulled changes from the remote repository, right? But if so then the store is at another revision than my working directory which is confirmed when invoking 'hg tip' (outputs rev 44) and 'hg parents' (outputs rev 43).

Comment: So they just are marked as removed. You need ton commit to make the repository register that "those files are removed". Then as there will be no other changes uncommited, you will be able to merge. Just keep in mind that 1. the repository have to keeps all the changes, including removes 2. mercurial can only merge registered change sets, not uncommitted changes.

Comment: @Chris> If you didn't commit, it's not stored. Did you commit after moving those file? They seem to be marked R because mercurial don't make the link between those files and the new location of those files.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to update my working directory to rev 44 instead of committing? I thought that committing means writing changes from the working directory to the store and updating means getting changesets from the store to the working directory?

Comment: @Klaim: I think I did something wrong after moving the files cause I've just added the moved files again and pushed them to the remote repository so I believe Mercurial does not know that there should be a link between the old and new location.

Comment: Err... Ok lets get to basics : commit => put changes in the LOCAL store. update=> change the local directory files to a specific revision. push => send LOCAL changes (those that have been commited) to another repository's store. pull => get the DISTANT changes from another repository and put them in the LOCAL store. merge => well, merge two changesets together, with their different parent changes.
So what I say is that when you do something locally, you then commit the change before being able to do any transaction (push/pull). A merge requires a (implicit) commit too, as it's a change too.

Comment: @Chris> Yes, I think it lost track because of the way you did it. If you have a graphical interface, maye using something like TortoiseHg would help? It helped me understand what's happening.